# DebeziumIO read with PostgresSQL to connect to RDS is not streaming data in Apache Beam

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, apache-beam, debezium, apache-beam-io

I have created apache beam pipeline which uses DebeziumIO - PostgreSQLconnector class to connect to postgresql in rds. The setup is working for local postgresql database with replication set to logical. AWS is setup with replication to logical and rds_replication role set to the user.
But the data stream is not captured by the pipeline.
I have checked with the embedded debezium with the postgresql connector class and it captures the change data.

Comment: To clarify, you're saying the pipeline works locally, but not on AWS? Is it perhaps a permissions issue?

Comment: Not a permission issue. Change data is captured with debezium embedded. But not with DebeziumIO